# Telerik UI for AspNet MVC 5 and DataSourceRequest

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

I recently installed Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Mvc5 (2019.2.619) into an application that previously used Kendo.MVC (2015). But now I get a message that "The type of namepsace name DataSourceRequest could not be found. What more do I need to install to get the DataSourceRequest object to work?

Do I need to install kendo.MVC? Or how do I get the Kendo.mvc.dll?

Answer (score 0):

I found the Kendo.mvc.dll inside Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC R2 2019\wrappers\aspnetmvc\Binaries\Mvc5 folder. 
Once I added that kendo.mvc.dll reference all the error messages about DataSourceRequest disappeared.